# How to use external IP address in Apache server

Tags: php, apache

Hi guys I am new to using apache server.

right now Apache server works with my "internal IP address" but I want it to use my "external IP address" to make my webpage publicly available.
How should I change the "httpd.conf" file to make this happen?

now I have

Listen 80

but when I change it to: "Listen external ip:80" I just get error message "the requested operation has failed"

could you please help me

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: which OS? are you hosting on your 'home' pc ?

Comment: Perhaps you have to configure a firewall.

Comment: windows 7 yes I am hostin on my home PC

Comment: do you have an IP specified or do you just have `<VirtualHost *:80>`? If you don't have an IP specified then you just need to make sure port 80 is being port forwarded to your internal IP address.

Comment: you mean I should open port 80 in my firewall?

Comment: You probably don't need to change your httpd.conf.  With your current config, the traffic just needs to get to the server.  You probably just need to modify your router's settings, which is off topic for this SO.

Comment: Pitchinnate I do not have <VirtualHost *:80> I just found my external IP address from "whatsmyip.org" and want to use it in apache. how can I do port forwarding?

Comment: Configure your router. Not Apache.

Comment: bad idea, get a cheap or free host.

Comment: Assuming you're using your home machine for this, you need to set up some sort of port forwarding on your router to hit your computer's port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Listen 80` will cause Apache to listen on all interfaces on the machine it is running on, so it is already listening on your external (to your machine) interface as well as your loopback (internal) interface.

If you want to make it available on the other side of a NAT set up, then you need to configure port forwarding on your router.

Comment: how should I do port forwarding? so after that I would be able to have  external Ip address as my webpage?

Comment: Consult the documentation for your router.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to an address that isn't assigned to one of the interfaces on the system. Bind to one of *those* addresses, and forward requests from the external address to that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should port forward any "80 HTTP" requests through to the host computer IP address that is running Apache. This process varies by your router manufacturer. Apache can only listen on the local machine that is running Apache. You cannot configure Apache to listen to the incoming "80" requests on any other device.

Comment: Can I use virtual host to make apache use my external IP?
I am sorry I am very new to this.